# How can I get the size after scaling on WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to change the size of the button. Then get the size of the button after scaling. Display the size on the label

```
MouseWheel += (ss, ee) =>
{
    Matrix mat = button.RenderTransform.Value;

    if (ee.Delta > 0) mat.ScalePrepend(1.1, 1.1);
    else mat.ScalePrepend(0.9, 0.9);

    button.RenderTransform = new MatrixTransform(mat);

    label.Content=??????;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Layout` is not effected by `RenderTransform`. But what based on the Scaling Matrix of which you provided I have calculated the approximate or close height and width.

If the Delta > 120 then you have given **X1** = 1.1 and **Y1** = 1.1 else **X2** = 0.9 and **Y2** = 0.9.

Based on the scaling matrix multiplication i have applied the same to find the height and width.

```
MouseWheel += (ss, ee) =>
{
        double width = Button5.ActualWidth;
        double height = Button5.ActualHeight;


        Label.Content = string.Empty;
        Matrix mat = Button5.RenderTransform.Value;

        if (ee.Delta > 0)
            mat.ScalePrepend(1.1, 1.1);
        else
            mat.ScalePrepend(0.9, 0.9);

        Button5.RenderTransform = new MatrixTransform(mat);

        height = height * (Button5.RenderTransform.Value.M11 );
        width = width * (Button5.RenderTransform.Value.M22 );

        Label.Content = String.Format($"Height -  {height} Width - {width}");
 };
```

Note:- The `ActualHeight` and `AcutalWidth` is not effected. This is only for display purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The unchanging values in ActualWidth and ActualHeight are natural because the changes applied are supposed to happen after render. That's the reason this should be very carefully used.

Same problem is detail discussed in

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5b7fbb2e-717c-44e2-8468-dcdf0a4ea28d/actualwidthheight-not-changed-by-rendertransform?forum=wpf